# Como obtengo el dato seleccionado de un combo?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Mi problema es que no sé cómo capturar el dato seleccionado de la lista del combobox, no me refiero al valor 1,2,3,4 me refiero a lo que muestra el combo, en mi caso nombres de equipos, los datos los traigo con js, y me inserta el valor numérico que seleccioné de la lista, y está bien, pero también necesito obtener e insertar el nombre del equipo, no sólo el valor.

Desde aquí extraigo los datos, filtrados por un id de departamento.

```
$query = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM equipos WHERE idDepto = $depto");

echo '<option value="0">Seleccione</option>';

while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<option value="' . $row['idEquipo'] . '">' . $row['Nombre'] . 
'</option>' . "\n";
 }
```

Con esta función Js los paso a HTML, donde en HTML sólo tomo "cmbequipos".

```
$(function(){

// Lista de Deptos
$.post( 'departamentos.php' ).done( function(respuesta)
{
    $( '#cmbdeptos' ).html( respuesta );
});

// lista de Deptos
$('#cmbdeptos').change(function()
{
    var el_continente = $(this).val();

    // Lista de Eqs
    $.post( 'equipos.php', { continente: el_continente} ).done( function( respuesta )
    {
        $( '#cmbequipos' ).html( respuesta );
    });
});

// Lista de Equipos
$( '#cmbequipos' ).change( function()
{
    var pais = $(this).children('option:selected').html();

});

 })
```

HTML Vista

```
<select name="cmbequipos" class="form-control input-sm" required="Yes" 
id="cmbequipos" <?php echo $_SESSION["status"]; ?>>
              </select>
```

Al momento de insertar pongo algo así `$var = $_POST['cmbequipos'];` pero me inserta el valor en este caso el id del Equipo. Pero trato de tomar el nombre en vez del valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logre solucionarlo, como unicamente insertaba el valor id, decidi que al momento de inserter hiciera una consulta y me trajera el nombre del equipo ya que me insertaba el id unicamente, quedo algo asi.

```
 //Consulta para seleccionar los valores de la bd
$sql = "SELECT Nombre FROM equipos WHERE idEquipo = " .$_POST['cmbequipos']."";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//contador de los valores extraidos en la consulta

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Datos obtenidos de la consulta

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {

        $NomEq = $row["Nombre"]; //Dato base requerido 
        $datos_insertar[54] = $NomEq;
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto

```
$('#cmbequipos').change(function() {
    var pais = $('#cmbequipos option:selected').html();
});
```

Comment: Hola @ArtValdez, podrías añadir algo más de contexto, explicar qué hace tu código y por qué crees que soluciona el problema de OP ? [answer]